# Rewrite URL - how to get the hostname and the path?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to use mod_rewrite to hide the URL, that generates my XML file.

So if this is the requested URL:

> **http://www.domain.com/path/to/**  **page** ? **cid=8001&srt=po**

This URL should be executed:

> http:// www.xmldomain.com/bla/**page** ? **cid=8001&srt=po** &rtype=xslt&xsl=**http://www.domain.com/path/to/**  **page** .xsl
>
> `http://www.xmldomain.com/bla/$2?$3&rtype=xslt&xsl=http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1$2.xsl*`

`%{HTTP_HOST}` is `www.domain.com`
`$1` should be `/path/to/` **(How can I do this?)**
`$2` should be `page`
`$3` should be `cid=8001&srt=po`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't tell exactly which urls you want to match, so I'll assume you want to match only http://www.domain.com/path/to/page, but write it a way that extending the rule to more general urls for the same domain is trivial. If you need more domains it can be done too. I also don't know what you mean with "hide". If you want to redirect instead of proxy, substitute the P flag inside the brackets with the R flag.

```
#should be put in the virtual host for www.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(/path/to/page)$ http://www.xmldomain.com/bla/page?rtype=xslt&xsl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com$1.xsl%2A [QSA,B,P,NE]
```

QSA appends cid and str parameters, B escapes the path, P proxies the request and NE avoids double encoding of the percent signs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit more dynamic one, should do exactly what you're looking for.

```
RewriteRule ^(http://[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)/([-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)\?([A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)$ http://www.xmldomain.com/bla/$2?$3&rtype=xslt&xsl=$1/$2.xsl
```

I have no idea what kind of options you want at the end, but I'd assume you'd want to use a redirect.

Comment: this is exactly what I'm looking for, but it doesn't work on my server. the page cannot be found. mod_rewrite is active, I've tried some trivial examples, and it's working. can you help me to find out what the problem is?

Comment: I opened a new thread for this. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880996/mod-rewrite-rewriterule-is-not-working